# How to collapse session path data into from-to paths for visualizing network data?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning, network-analysis

What are some ways to transform session path data such as this:

```
df
#   Session Link1 Link2 Link3 Link4 Link5
# 1       1     A     B                  
# 2       2     C                        
# 3       3     D     A     B            
# 4       4     C     F     G     H     J
# 5       5     A     B     C
```

Into a data set that looks like this:

```
desired
#    Session From   To
# 1        1    A    B
# 2        2    C <NA>
# 3        3    D    A
# 4        3    A    B
# 5        4    C    F
# 6        4    F    G
# 7        4    G    H
# 8        4    H    J
# 9        5    A    B
# 10       5    B    C
```

Data for reproducibility:

```
df <- structure(list(Session = 1:5, Link1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Link2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("", "A", "B", "F"), class = "factor"), Link3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("", "B", "C", "G"), class = "factor"), Link4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "H"), class = "factor"), Link5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "J"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Session", "Link1", "Link2", "Link3", "Link4", "Link5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
desired <- structure(list(Session = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), From = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H"), class = "factor"), To = structure(c(2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "F", "G", "H", "J"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Session", "From", "To"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Reshape from 'wide' to 'long' format with `melt` specifying the `id.var` as 'Session'.  Remove the 'value' elements that are empty `[value!='']`.  Grouped by 'Session', we insert 'NA' values in the 'value' column for those 'Session' that have only a single row (`if...else`), create a two columns ('From' and 'To') by removing the last and first element of 'V1' grouped by 'Session'.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 melt(setDT(df), id.var='Session')[value!=''][, 
   if(.N==1L) c(value, NA) else value, by = Session][,
      list(From=V1[-.N], To=V1[-1L]), by = Session]
 #   Session From To
 #1:       1    A  B
 #2:       2    C NA
 #3:       3    D  A
 #4:       3    A  B
 #5:       4    C  F
 #6:       4    F  G
 #7:       4    G  H
 #8:       4    H  J
 #9:       5    A  B
 #10:      5    B  C
```

The above could be simplified to a single block after the `melt` step.  For some reason, `tmp[-.N]` is not working.  So I used `tmp[1:(.N-1)]`.

```
melt(setDT(df), id.var= 'Session')[value!='', {
              tmp <- if(.N==1L) c(value, NA) else value
              list(From= tmp[1:(.N-1)], To= tmp[-1L]) }, by = Session]
#    Session From To
#1:       1    A  B
#2:       2    C NA
#3:       3    D  A
#4:       3    A  B
#5:       4    C  F
#6:       4    F  G
#7:       4    G  H
#8:       4    H  J
#9:       5    A  B
#10:      5    B  C
```

Comment: This is very fancy. My solution doesn't come even close.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I (and probably others) would appreciate some less fancy versions too - mind you, I'm not taking away from @akrun's `data.table` magic.

Comment: @akrun's answer is the right one, but I added another version without the black magic sorcery : )

Comment: @PierreLafortune  I didn't know that a dplyr/tidyr solution was already added as the page didn't update.

Comment: That was added by the OP. I think the `data.table` solution works best. Especially for scale.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns wrap the result into a `as.data.frame` et voila. :)

Comment: @PierreLafortune agreed with the scale comment, but I added my own for clarity and others and this was before akrun added the explanation.

Comment: Check out my solution for `dplyr` approach. When you use `lag` in yours you create extra work for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @akrun, this is my personal stab at the problem. Granted, the results are tweaked to include the terminal from-to path for each pair:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(df, "Link_Num", "Value", -Session) %>%
  group_by(Session) %>%
  mutate(to = Value,
         from = lag(to)) %>%
  filter(Link_Num != "Link1" &
         from != "") %>%
  select(Session, from, to, Link_Num) %>%
  arrange(Session)
```

Which yields:

```
   Session from to Link_Num
1        1    A  B    Link2
2        1    B       Link3
3        2    C       Link2
4        3    D  A    Link2
5        3    A  B    Link3
6        3    B       Link4
7        4    C  F    Link2
8        4    F  G    Link3
9        4    G  H    Link4
10       4    H  J    Link5
11       5    A  B    Link2
12       5    B  C    Link3
13       5    C       Link4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `dplyr` functions `melt` and `lead`:

```
library(dplyr)
df$spacer <- ""
df %>% melt(id.var = "Session") %>%
  arrange(Session) %>% 
  mutate(To = lead(value)) %>%
  filter(To !="" & value !="" | To =="" & variable =="Link1") %>%
  mutate(To = ifelse(To == "", NA, To)) %>% select(-variable)
#    Session value   To
# 1        1     A    B
# 2        2     C <NA>
# 3        3     D    A
# 4        3     A    B
# 5        4     C    F
# 6        4     F    G
# 7        4     G    H
# 8        4     H    J
# 9        5     A    B
# 10       5     B    C
```

Comment: I have a doubt with your solution.  Are you using the data.table `lead` or the `dplyr` one?   Also, looks like you are using the `base R` methods.  This could be translated to `data.table`

Comment: I'm using base methods with `dplyr` lead. You think it's better to not mix methods?

Comment: You can mention the package used for better clarity.

Comment: @akrun I tried putting the conditional into a dplyr pipe but having no luck. I tried `filter(value2 != "" & value ...`

Comment: Ok I used `dplyr::filter` and it's better. I wonder if there's a way to force which type of filter to mask in the pipe?

Comment: I posted a more complete dplyr solution. Let me know if it is a better solution. @akrun

Comment: Looks fine.  I would use `gather` from `tidyr` or specify that you are using `reshape2`

Comment: I noticed that you have a `J A`  combination for `Session` 4, which is not in the expected output of the OP

Comment: Nice catch. I will add a spacer column. Not ideal, but it will get the job done.